# Gauss' proof of the irreducibility of a cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $l$ be an odd prime number.
Let $f(X) = 1 + X + ... + X^{l-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$.
Probably Gauss was the first man who proved that $f(X)$ is irreducible.
I wonder how he proved it.

Comment: You mean because it is usually proved using Eisenstein's criterion, and Eisenstein came later?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Gauss proved it before 1800. Eisenstein was born in 1823.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did not know the precise dates, but I knew Eisenstein was later (maybe even a student of Gauss, or maybe of Riemann?)

Comment: By the way, I heard that someone already published the Eisenstein's theorem before him. So that the name of the theorem may not be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I think I have seen that mentioned too. But everyone knows the name of Eisenstein's criterion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first proof presented [here](http://www.lehigh.edu/~shw2/c-poly/several_proofs.pdf) is a proof by Gauss. The original is in Gauss' magnum opus  [Disquisitiones Arithmeticae](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387962549).

Comment: It's a modified version but there's a cite to the original version in the footnotes.

Comment: That's great. Thanks!